# How to convert string to Workbook name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub openwb()

Dim x260path As String

x260path = "E:\sarath\PTMetrics\20131002\D8 L538-L550 16MY\D8 L538-L550_16MY_Powertrain Metrics_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") - 1

Workbooks("x260path").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ["E:\sarath\PTMetrics\20131002\D8 L538-L550 16MY\D8 L538-L550_16MY_Powertrain Metrics_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")]

Debug.Print x260path

End Sub
```

Here, when i execute, an error says "subscript out of Range". And it appears on 4th line.when i use 'workbook' to declare 'x260path' instead of string, It shows another error saying "Object variable or with block variable not set" on line 3. Can u help?Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA the equivalent function to `=Today()` is `Date()` (*or `Date`)

```
x260path = CONCATENATE("..." & Date)
```

Alternatively, use `Now()` function ( that includes a time stamp as well though )

```
x260path = CONCATENATE("..." & Now)
```

---

```
debug.print Date
```

> 02/10/2013

and

```
debug.print Now
```

> 02/10/2013 08:39:20

---

some of the spreadsheet functions are available to use with the `WorksheetFunction` class. For example

```
Sub Main()

    Dim sum As Double
    sum = WorksheetFunction.sum(10, 20)
    MsgBox sum

End Sub
```

Note: when you type the `sum = WorksheetFunction.` as soon as you type in the `.` you should get the VBA's Intelli-sense help. It is a list of all available functions you can use with the WorksheetFunction class.

[image]

In your case the `=Concatenate` function is equivalent to `&` operator in VBA. Therefore the easiest way would be to *join* two string using the `&`

```
x260path = "C:\..." & date
```

If a function you are trying to use doesn't exist in the Intelli-sense you can create your own UDF or you can do some online research on how the function works and how to overwrite it.

Comment: That worked. But now the same error shows for CONCATENATE() function.

Comment: @srt well, yeah becuase Concatenate again inst a valid VBA function.  see my updated answer

Comment: you said '=Concatenate' is equivalent to '&' operator in VBA...How is that so??..

Comment: `=Concatenate` joins two strings together so does `&` in VBA. You can use `&` operator in the spreadsheet formula too. For example instead of `=Concatenate("arg1", "arg2")` you can say `="arg1" & "arg2"`